# htaccess with sub folders and page with the same name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `work.html` and a folder called `work` that has many pages inside. Every page appears without the `.html` in the URL, but when I go back to `example.com/work` I get a 404, but it works fine when I type `example.com/work.html`.

For reference,

- `example.com/work/piece1` works fine
- `example.com/work/piece2` works fine

Should I have something else in the htaccess?

I'm using this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: The first RewriteCond will likely not be true here, I suppose it recognizes that a folder `work` exists. And since multiple conditions are joined by an implicit AND, the fact that the second one should be true, doesn't save it any more at this point.

Comment: @Owen How did you get on with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a `work.html` and a folder called `work` ... Every page appears without the html in the URL, but when I go back to `example.com/work` I get a 404.

*Aside:* Ordinarily I would have expected this to have resulted in a 403, not a 404, unless perhaps mod_autoindex is not installed on your server? (Or there are other directives in the `.htaccess` file?)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
> ```

As @CBroe pointed out in comments, the first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) specifically excludes "directories" (physical directories on the filesystem), so when requesting a directory (ie. `/work`) the rule is bypassed.

So, that first condition needs to be removed. (It's unnecessary to check both anyway... that the request does not map to a directory before checking that the request+`.html` does map to a file - these are two mutually exclusive events, unless you have directories with a `.html` extension?!)

However, that's only part of the problem, you can't simply remove that *condition* and expect this to work. Since `/work` is a physical directory mod_dir will try to append a trailing slash with a 301 redirect (in order to "fix" the URL). So `/work` is redirected to `/work/`, which then causes the rule to internally rewrite the request to `/work/.html` (since `REQUEST_FILENAME` does not include the trailing slash*****) - which then causes a 404. You need to prevent mod_dir from "fixing" the URL with the `DirectorySlash Off` directive. But therein lies further issues... directory listings *must* be disabled to prevent accidental disclosure of your file structure (if mod_autoindex is installed and enabled) and any `DirectoryIndex` documents in subdirectories will no longer be accessible (unless you manually check for this and append the trailing slash as required).

(***** That's another issue with this rule... the condition that checks whether the corresponding `.html` file exists is not testing the same thing that you are ultimately rewriting to in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string.)

So, you should write the rule like this instead:

```
# Disable directory listings (mod_autoindex)
Options -MultiViews -Indexes

# Prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash to directories
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Append ".html" extension if the target file exists.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule (.+) $1.html [L]
```

The `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive is not required here, since the pattern already matches both lower and uppercase letters.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect that appended the trailing slash will have been cached by the browser.

You can further optimise the above "extensionless" rewrite by excluding requests that already contain a file extension (ie. physical files), or perhaps just exclude your static assets subdirectory. (This is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Needless to say, it would be preferable to avoid the situation of having a file with the same basename as an existing directory when managing extensionless URLs, since it naturally creates an ambiguity.